# A conjecture regarding sums of consecutive powers

Tags: number-theory

Is it true that for any $n \ge 2$, there is a tuple of $n+1$ consecutive natural numbers such that the sum of the $n$th powers of the first $n$ natural numbers is equal to the $n$th power of the last natural number? I was led to this conjecture after seeing the pattern hold for $(3,4,5)$ and $(3,4,5,6)$. It does not hold for $(3,4,5,6,7)$, but I wonder if a length $5$ tuple exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such tuple of length $5$ exists. In particular, we can suppose that your tuple is of the form $(a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4)$ and satisfies:
$$a^4+(a+1)^4+(a+2)^4+(a+3)^4=(a+4)^4$$
or, equivalently
$$a^4+(a+1)^4+(a+2)^4+(a+3)^4-(a+4)^4=0$$
Now, this makes clear that we're just looking for the root to a polynomial in $a$. We can expand each of the products above (for instance, by asking [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand%5Ba%5E4%2B%28a%2B1%29%5E4%2B%28a%2B2%29%5E4%2B%28a%2B3%29%5E4-%28a%2B4%29%5E5%5D)) to get
$$3a^4 + 8a^3 - 12a^2 - 112 a -158=0$$
and then using the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) we can see that the only possible rational solutions $\frac{p}q$ have that $p$ is a factor of $158$ (i.e. one of $\pm 1,\,\pm 2,\,\pm 79,\pm 158$) and $q$ is a factor of $3$ (i.e. $1$ or $3$). Testing yields that none of these are roots, so no integral (nor rational) $a$ works to create such a tuple.

One may also plot this polynomial, and simply note that it doesn't have any roots at integers; knowing a little bit about the general behavior of polynomials (of low degree) tells us that nothing surprising will happen that a graph can't show us.

Comment: @WillJagy Well, I'm apparently too tired for math, but it seems like the largest real root of $a^n+(a+1)^n+\ldots + (a+n-1)^n - (a+n)^n$ increases with $n$ and, just by plotting these function, can be seen to be less than $4$ for $n=5$ and more than $4$ for $n=6$. I'm not sure how one would address the more general question of whether there are any other tuples with the property mentioned by the OP.

Comment: agreed. I am looking in Guy's book on unsolved problems, the smallest for quartics is due to Norrie, 1911, $30^4 + 120^4 + 272^4 + 315^4 = 353^4.$ Makes me feel that these solutions are not frequent enough, as the exponent increases, to expect consecutive entries.

Comment: no consecutive for exponents 4,5,6,7,8.